# PHP AJAX JSON autosuggest

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I cannot get the dropdown field to "autosuggest".

I have my main page, which is bpSearch.php, where I have a modal window with an input field that, when you begin typing, it should autosuggest data that is being called from my search file.

Here is the input inside the modal:

```
 <input type="text" class="autosuggest" id="partnerName" name="partnerName" placeholder="Partner Name" />
 <div class="dropdown">
   <ul class="result"></ul>
 </div>
```

Here is my javascript, called searchPartner.js, that is sending the RESULT to the search file:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   $('.autosuggest').keyup(function()
   {
     var search_term = $(this).attr('value');
     $.post('api/searchPartner.php', {search_term:search_term}, function(data)
     {
       $('.result').html(data);
       $('.result li').click(function()
       {
         var result_value = $(this).text();
         $('.autosuggest').attr('value', result_value);
       });
     });
   });
 });
```

And here is my search file, called searchPartner.php.  As you can see in the JavaScript, it is located in a folder called api.  Perhaps I'm not traversing to the directory correctly? Here is searchPartner.php:

```
 <?php
   include("../include/database.php");
   if(isset($_POST['search_term']) == true && empty($_POST['search_term']) == false)
   {
     $search_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['search_term']);
     $search = "SELECT PARTNER_CODE, FULL_NAME FROM partner WHERE FULL_NAME LIKE '$search_term%'";
     $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $search);
     while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false)
     {
       echo '<li>', $row['FULL_NAME'], '</li>';
     }
   }
 ?>
```

I know this query works, because I've opened the page, commented out the IF statement, and I can see the LI tags with the $row{'FULL_NAME'].  So all I need to do is get my main page to retrieve this data when the user begins typing.

Comment: Try changing `name="partnerName"` to `name="search_term"`. Seems to me anyway. I don't see a form element named "search_term".

Comment: I don't see anything obvious. What exactly do you see being returned for the ajax call in your dev console?

Comment: This however, `mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['search_term'])` needs a DB connection parameter `mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['search_term'])` that is **100% for sure**. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php `string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`

Comment: ^^^^^ That. And you might want to use absolute paths relative to the root of the web-server for your assets / ajax script and relative to the root of your file-server for your includes.

Comment: @dgig, I checked Chrome's console.  The UL is not producing any LI's elements.  What do you think?

Comment: Because MySQL can't find it. See my comment above ^^^ about `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I made that correction as stated, but still no results.

Comment: Well, it's definitely a contributing factor. What about my first comment?

Comment: I could be wring, but I don't think so fred, because he is sending the data directly as json. he's not sending it through a form.

Comment: @dgig No, it doesn't matter. Please read the documentation on `mysqli_real_escape_string()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php OP is using `$search_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['search_term']);` it's a contributing factor.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, I made the first change as well.

Comment: What about changing `$('.result li')` to `$('.result ul')` since you have it inside `<ul class="result"></ul>` a `ul` and not an `li` ^^^

Comment: @Fred-ii- damn...all of your suggestions were so promising.  I made the attempt to switch it from LI to UL to no avail. Maybe my path is incorrect.

Comment: That could also be another contributing factor as Jeroen mentioned earlier. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Plus, you do have the jQuery libraries loaded, and the right doctype?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think I might know the problem. The table, called partner, is such a large table, holding over 2 million records. I tried to show the JSON to the page, but it conks out. When I limit it to about 500, that's when it displays to the screen. Problem is, I change the LIMIT in my query to 10 and still no results.  I have failed.

Comment: Is your table indexed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to try

```
// var search_term = $(this).attr('value');
var search_term_2 = $(this).val();
$.post('api/searchPartner.php', {search_term:search_term_2}, function(data)
// ...
```

Sorry the search_term:search_term was just confusing me...
But rather than looking at the attr value , just get the val()

```
 <input type="text" class="autosuggest" id="partnerName" name="partnerName" placeholder="Partner Name" value="No Values Here Man..." />
```

not sure if this'll help though